# Expand a list tag (li) vertically to dynamically include text in several lines in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working with [this](https://jsfiddle.net/heba0/0m4qdvja/4/) jsfiddle from [this](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/z1VWK) snippet and I am trying to fit a two-line text into one of the list item, where "rest of the text need to show" is currently hidden.

For my project, I might need to display list items that will up take more than two lines, so is there a way in css/javascipt to wrap the list around the text

```
 <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">       
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                item 1<br>rest of the text need to show
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                item 2         
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                item 3

            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: The question is not clear for me. Maybe just remove the height of the `a` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the fixed height from the `a` tag and the element height will match the size of the content inside of it. Here's an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0m4qdvja/5/

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic&subset=latin,cyrillic";

/* -- import Roboto Font ---------------------------- */


/* -- import Material Icons Font -------------------- */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Design Iconic Font';
  src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53474/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.eot?v=1.0');
  src: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53474/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.eot?#iefix&v=1.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53474/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.woff?v=1.0') format('woff'), url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53474/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.ttf?v=1.0') format('truetype'), url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/53474/Material-Design-Iconic-Font.svg?v=1.0#Material-Design-Iconic-Font') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="md-"],
[class*=" md-"] {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 'Material Design Iconic Font';
  font-size: inherit;
  speak: none;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.md {
  line-height: inherit;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.md-inbox:before {
  content: "\f10c";
}

.md-star:before {
  content: "\f2e5";
}

.md-send:before {
  content: "\f119";
}

.md-drafts:before {
  content: "\f107";
}

.md-arrow-back:before {
  content: "\f297";
}

.md-arrow-forward:before {
  content: "\f298";
}


/* -- You can use this sidebar in Bootstrap (v3) projects. HTML-markup like Navbar bootstrap component will make your work easier. -- */


/* -- Box model ------------------------------- */

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* -- Demo style ------------------------------- */

html,
body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'RobotoDraft', 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

.sidebar-overlay {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 1034;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0 linear 0.4s, opacity 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  -moz-transition: visibility 0 linear 0.4s, opacity 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  transition: visibility 0 linear 0.4s, opacity 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.sidebar-overlay.active {
  opacity: 0.5;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
  -moz-transition-delay: 0;
  transition-delay: 0;
}

.top-bar {
  height: 25px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


/* -- Google typography ------------------------------- */

.headline {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.1;
  color: #212121;
  text-transform: inherit;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
}

.subhead {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.1;
  color: #212121;
  text-transform: inherit;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
}


/* -- Bootstrap-like style ------------------------------- */

.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px solid;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}


/* -- Constructor style ------------------------------- */

.constructor {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 50px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
}

.sidebar,
.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.sidebar-stacked.open + .wrapper .constructor {
  margin-left: 280px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-stacked.open + .wrapper .constructor {
    margin-left: 240px;
  }
}


/* -- Sidebar style ------------------------------- */

.sidebar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
}

.sidebar:before,
.sidebar:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.sidebar:after {
  clear: both;
}

.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.sidebar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #BFBFBF;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-header {
  position: relative;
  height: 157.5px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-header.header-cover {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-header:hover .sidebar-toggle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: none;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-toggle:before,
.sidebar .sidebar-toggle:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-toggle:after {
  clear: both;
}

.sidebar .icon-material-sidebar-arrow:before {
  content: "\e610";
}

.sidebar .sidebar-image img {
  width: 54px;
  height: 54px;
  margin: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-brand {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 56px;
  text-decoration: none;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 500;
  overflow: hidden;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-brand:hover,
.sidebar .sidebar-brand:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-brand .caret {
  position: absolute;
  right: 24px;
  top: 24px;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-brand .sidebar-badge {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 12px;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-brand:hover,
.sidebar .sidebar-brand:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-badge {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 0 3px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-badge.badge-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-divider,
.sidebar .sidebar-nav .divider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-text {
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 56px;
  text-decoration: none;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 500;
  overflow: hidden;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-text:hover,
.sidebar .sidebar-text:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-text .caret {
  position: absolute;
  right: 24px;
  top: 24px;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-text .sidebar-badge {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 12px;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 16px;
  min-width: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-icon:before,
.sidebar .sidebar-icon:after {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-nav li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-nav li a {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 56px;
  text-decoration: none;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: 500;
  overflow: hidden;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-nav li a:hover,
.sidebar .sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-nav li a .caret {
  position: absolute;
  right: 24px;
  top: 24px;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-nav li a .sidebar-badge {
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;
  top: 12px;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  background: transparent;
}

.sidebar .sidebar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.sidebar-default {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-header {
  background-color: #eceff1;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-toggle {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-brand {
  color: #757575;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-brand:hover,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-brand:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-badge {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-divider,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav .divider {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-text {
  color: #212121;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li > a {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li > a i {
  color: #757575;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li:hover > a,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li > a:hover {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li:hover > a i,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li > a:hover i {
  color: #757575;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li:focus > a,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li > a:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li:focus > a i,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav li > a:focus i {
  color: #757575;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .open > a,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .active > a,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #e0e0e0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  color: #212121;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #cecece;
  color: #212121;
}

.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.sidebar-default .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar-inverse {
  background-color: #212121;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-header {
  background-color: #eceff1;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-toggle {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-brand {
  color: #757575;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-brand:hover,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-brand:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-badge {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-divider,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav .divider {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-text {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav li > a {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav li > a i {
  color: #bdbdbd;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav li:hover > a,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav li > a:hover {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav li:hover > a i,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav li > a:hover i {
  color: #bdbdbd;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav li:focus > a,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav li > a:focus {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav li:focus > a i,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav li > a:focus i {
  color: #bdbdbd;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .open > a,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .active > a,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #757575;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #bdbdbd;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #bdbdbd;
}

.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.sidebar-inverse .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.sidebar-colored {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-header {
  background-color: #e91e63;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-toggle {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-brand {
  color: #e0e0e0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-brand:hover,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-brand:focus {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-badge {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #ec407a;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-divider,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav .divider {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-text {
  color: #212121;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav li > a {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav li > a i {
  color: #757575;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav li:hover > a,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav li > a:hover {
  color: #e91e63;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav li:hover > a i,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav li > a:hover i {
  color: #f06292;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav li:focus > a,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav li > a:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav li:focus > a i,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav li > a:focus i {
  color: #f06292;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .open > a,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #e91e63;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .active > a,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #e0e0e0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  color: #e91e63;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #cecece;
  color: #e91e63;
}

.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.sidebar-colored .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse {
  background-color: #e91e63;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-header {
  background-color: #eceff1;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-toggle {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-brand {
  color: #757575;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-brand:hover,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-brand:focus {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-badge {
  color: #212121;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-divider,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav .divider {
  background-color: #bdbdbd;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-text {
  color: #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav li > a {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav li > a i {
  color: #e0e0e0;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav li:hover > a,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav li > a:hover {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav li:hover > a i,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav li > a:hover i {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav li:focus > a,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav li > a:focus {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav li:focus > a i,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav li > a:focus i {
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .open > a,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .open > a:hover,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .active > a,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a:hover,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .disabled > a:focus {
  color: #bdbdbd;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #f5f5f5;
}

.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a:hover,
.sidebar-colored-inverse .sidebar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .active > a:focus {
  color: #f5f5f5;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.sidebar {
  width: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-280px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(-280px, 0, 0);
}

.sidebar.open {
  min-width: 280px;
  width: 280px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.sidebar-fixed-left,
.sidebar-fixed-right,
.sidebar-stacked {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 1035;
}

.sidebar-stacked {
  left: 0;
}

.sidebar-fixed-left {
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

.sidebar-fixed-right {
  right: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(280px, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(280px, 0, 0);
}

.sidebar-fixed-right.open {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.sidebar-fixed-right .icon-material-sidebar-arrow:before {
  content: "\e614";
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar.open {
    min-width: 240px;
    width: 240px;
  }
  .sidebar .sidebar-header {
    height: 135px;
  }
  .sidebar .sidebar-image img {
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
  }
}
```

```html
<aside id="sidebar" class="sidebar sidebar-default open" role="navigation">
  <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
    <li>
      <a href="#">
                item 1<br>rest of the text need to show
            </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
                item 2         
            </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
                item 3
               
            </a>
    </li>
  </ul>


  <!-- Sidebar text -->
  <!--  <div class="sidebar-text">Text</div> -->
</aside>
```

Comment: Thanks! that was helpful, but could you point out the line number for the height that you just edited

Comment: @heba it's the rule under `.sidebar .sidebar-nav li a`, line 364

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/heba0/0m4qdvja/4/

```
.style{
    display:inline-block;
    width:180px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden !important;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```